# Complex integral of product of two polynomial powers

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

> Compute $$\int_{|z|=1}z^n\left(z-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^mdz$$ where $m,n$ are integers.

If $m,n\geq 0$, the function is entire, and so the integral is $0$.

If $n<0$ and $m\geq 0$, the function becomes $\dfrac{\left(z-\dfrac12\right)^m}{z^{|n|}}$. This can be handled by the Cauchy formula. Let $f(z)=\left(z-\dfrac12\right)^m$. Then the integral is $\dfrac{2\pi i}{|n-1|!}\cdot f^{(|n-1|)}(0)$.

If $m<0$ and $n\geq 0$, it should be similar.

But what if $m,n<0$? Now there are two values for which the denominator vanish. How can we use Cauchy's theorem or otherwise?

**Edit**: Since this exercise appears in Ahlfors many sections before the Residue theorem, I would like to see a solution that doesn't use Residue theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\displaystyle{%
> \int_{\left\vert\, z\,\right\vert\ =\ 1}
> z^{n}\left(z- {1 \over2}\right)^{m}\,{\rm d}z:\ {\large ?}\\[5mm]
> }$

In general, we have two expansion of the integrand:

1. $$
   z^{n}\left(z- {1 \over2}\right)^{m}
   =
   \left(-1\right)^{m}
   \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{m \choose \ell}{1 \over 2^{m - \ell}}\,
   {\left(-1\right)^{\ell} \over z^{-n - \ell}}    
   $$
2. $$
   z^{n}\left(z- {1 \over2}\right)^{m}
   =
   \left[{1 \over 2} + \left(z - {1 \over 2}\right)\right]^{n}\left(z- {1 \over2}\right)^{m}
   =
   \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose \ell}{1 \over 2^{n - \ell}}\,
   {1 \over \left(z - 1/2\right)^{-m - \ell}}    
   $$

where $\displaystyle{x \choose y}$ is the
$\it\underline{\mbox{generalized binomial coefficient}}$ as explained
[here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html).

When $m \leq -1$ and $n \leq -1$ ( $m$ and $n$ integers ) we have to consider both poles: At $z = 0$ and at $z = 1/2$. The result turns out to be:
\begin{align}
\int_{\left\vert\, z\,\right\vert\ =\ 1}
z^{n}\left(z- {1 \over2}\right)^{m}\,{\rm d}z
&=
2\pi{\rm i}\left[%
{m \choose -n - 1}\left(-\,{1 \over 2}\right)^{m + n + 1}
+
{n \choose -m - 1}{1 \over 2^{n + m + 1}}\right]
\\[3mm]&=
2\pi{\rm i}\left[%
{n \choose -m - 1} + \left(-1\right)^{m + n + 1}{m \choose -n - 1}
\right]\,{1 \over 2^{m + n + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=
2\pi{\rm i}\left[%
\left(-1\right)^{m + 1}{-m - n - 2 \choose -m - 1}
+
\left(-1\right)^{m}{-m - n - 2\choose -n - 1}
\right]\,{1 \over 2^{m + n + 1}}
\\&
\phantom{%
\left[%
{n \choose -m - 1} + \left(-1\right)^{m + n + 1}{m \choose -n - 1}
\right]}
m, n \in {\mathbb Z}\,,\quad m \leq -1\,,\quad n \leq -1.
\end{align}

Comment: What formula do you use in the line after "The results turns out to be"?

Comment: Cauchy's Residue Theorem:
$\displaystyle{\large\int_{\left\vert z\right\vert = 1}
{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,{1 \over z^{k}}
=
\delta_{k,1}}$.   

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: Okay, thank you. As I said in the edit, though, I would still like to see a way without the residue theorem.

Comment: Without RT, we just replace $\displaystyle{\large z = {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta}}$. We get $\displaystyle{\large\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}\left(k - 1\right)\theta}\ {{\rm d}\theta \over 2\pi} = \delta_{k,1}}$

Answer (score 1):

Residue theorem.  The residue of $z^{-j} (z - 1/2)^{-k}$ at $z=0$, for example,
is the coefficient of $z^{j-1}$ in the Maclaurin series of $(z-1/2)^{-k}$, which you can find using the binomial series.

Comment: That's interesting.. this exercise appears in Ahlfors before Residue Theorem (in fact, many sections before it!) Is there a way to do without Residue Theorem?